# Getting 502 instead of 503 when all backend servers are down running HAProxy behind Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, load-balancing, reverse-proxy, haproxy

I'm testing running HAProxy as a dedicated load balancer behind Apache 2.2, replacing our current configuration where we use Apache's load balancer.  In our current, Apache only, set-up if all the backend (origin) servers are down Apache will serve a 503 service unavailable message.  With HAProxy I get a 502 bad gateway response.

I'm using a simple reverse proxy rewrite rule in Apache

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://127.0.0.1:8000/$1 [last,proxy]
```

In HAProxy I have the following (running in default tcp mode)

```
defaults
    log             global
    option          tcp-smart-accept
    timeout connect 7s
    timeout client  60s
    timeout queue   120s
    timeout server  60s

listen my_server 127.0.0.1:8000
    balance leastconn
    server backend1 127.0.0.1:8001 check observe layer4 maxconn 2
    server backend1 127.0.0.1:8001 check observe layer4 maxconn 2
```

Testing connecting directly to the load balancer when the backend servers are down:

```
[root@dev ~]# wget http://127.0.0.1:8000/ test.html
--2012-05-28 11:45:28--  http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:8000... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... No data received.
```

So presumably this is down to the fact that HAProxy accepts the connection and then closes it.

Comment: Why are you putting apache in front of HAProxy?

Comment: We already have Apache but aren't satisfied with its load balancer and are switching to HAProxy instead.  Apache is also serving as our SSL endpoint, cache server as well as a reverse proxy.  We have years worth of rewrite rules and 10s of sites so getting rid of Apache completely is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't get this working in tcp mode but if you switch to http mode then you do get the 503

```
defaults
    mode http
```

Answer (score 5):

In TCP mode, haproxy does not emit any status code so the only remaining point clearly is apache. I think that it's simply because haproxy accepts then closes the connection that makes apache return a 502, which is expected.

So the behaviour you're observing is correct. Anyway it's generally better to work in HTTP mode. I also suggest that you enable "option httplog" which will provide you with very detailed logs, and "option http-server-close" to take advantage of apache's ability to maintain keep-alive with haproxy, it will significantly reduce local source port consumption on the machine.